# J2ME GameCanvas recognizing keys

Tags: java, java-me

I want to recognize some keys in my J2ME project - namely the star (*) key or the command buttons.
`getKeyStates()` doesn't work, and even when I used `keyPressed()` (or `keyReleased()`, which is incredibly slow) it doesn't recognize the key.

It seems that NetBeans doesn't even recognize the star key as a valid key press (as in, doesn't call the keyPressed event.)

My code is:

```
protected void keyPressed(int keyCode)
{
    int ga = getGameAction(keyCode);

    switch (ga)
    {
        case (LEFT):
        {
        }
        break;

        case (RIGHT):
        {
        }
        break;

        case (DOWN):
        {

        }
        break;

        case (UP):
        {
        }
        break;

        case (KEY_STAR):
        {
        }
        break;

        case (KeySoft1):
        {
        }
        break;
    }

    switch (keyCode)
    {
        case (KeyFire):
        {
            //Act accordigly to the situation.
            fbButton.FirePressed();
        }
        break;

        case (KeySoft1):
        {
            fbButton.FirePressed();
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

I'm using NetBeans 6.5.1, MIDP 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Canvas.KEY_STAR`](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Canvas.html#KEY_STAR) is a `keyCode` rather than a `gameAction`.

```
if (keyCode == Canvas.KEY_STAR) {
    System.out.println("That's the Star");
}
```